# Some identity with a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be a complex function. 
I've got the following equation to prove: $$I_f(z) = |\frac{df}{dz}|^2 - |\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}|^2 $$, where $I$ is determinant of Jacobian matrix.
But knowing that $ \frac{df}{dz} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{df}{dx} -i \frac{df}{dy})$ and $ \frac{df}{d\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{df}{dx} +i \frac{df}{dy})$, I obtain $|\frac{df}{dz}|^2 - |\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}|^2 = 0$. And deteminant of Jacobian matrix is not always equal to 0. Where do I make a mistake? Can you show me how to prove this identity correctly?

Comment: It's better to write exactly your steps in the body of your question.

Comment: Note that $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{df}{dy}$ are not necessarily real.

Comment: $\vert z\vert^2=z.\bar z=\vert \bar z\vert^2$. So there is something wrong with definition of $df/dz$ and $df/d\bar z$ definition

Comment: @Katsu These are the usual definitions for complex functions interpreted as $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @WimC : This is not what I meant by definition, I mean the equality.

Comment: @Katsu $\frac{df}{d\overline{z}}$ is not the same as $\overline{\left(\frac{df}{dz}\right)}$.

Comment: @WimC, you're right, they don't have to be real. How to write $|\frac{df}{dz}|^2 - |\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}|^2$ then? When we don't know which part is real?

Comment: @WimC: I know. I mean I'm not sure of the first equality. this is more like $I=\frac{dP}{dx}\frac{dQ}{dy}-\frac{dQ}{dx}\frac{dP}{dy}$ with $f=P+iQ$

Comment: @Anne Write $f = \alpha + i \beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$ and expand everything.

Answer (score 2):

Proof is helped by the identity  $|a+b|^2-|a-b|^2 = 4\operatorname{Re}(a\bar b)$:
\begin{split}
I_f & =  \frac14 |f_x-if_y|^2  - \frac14 |f_x+if_y|^2 \\
& = \operatorname{Re}( i f_x \overline{f_y}) \\
&= \operatorname{Re}\left(i(u_x+iv_x)\overline{(u_y+iv_y)}\right) \\ 
& = u_xv_y-u_y v_x
\end{split}